# JVM Crash:org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BestMatchSpec.formatCookies(Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List;

Tags: java, cookies, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm

The JVM which has a Web service on it almost crashes 1 time a day. And it generates hs_err_pid.log. 
The content is:

> Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
>
> J org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BestMatchSpec.formatCookies(Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List
>
> [error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xb]

So I study the gc.log, and find that JVM doesn't excute Full GC. It's very strange.
[gc.log summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6etTr.png)

I also use Memory Analyzer to study the memory and find that com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver use most of the memory and cause a memory leak. The content is:

[Memory Analyzer output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viYG3.png)

Do you ever meet such problems? How do you solve it?

The JVM version is ：

> java version "1.7.0_79"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

And the operation system is:
Linux x86_64/CentOS release 6.5

Comment: GC and memory logs are not relevant to a hard jvm crash. Post the full `hs_err_pid.log`, although an error during printing native stacks may render it useless. You should also mention JVM version and operating system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the full hs_err_pid.log is too long to upload.